dual boot Ubuntu 24.04 on installed Ubuntu Studio 24.04
I have recently installed Ubuntu Studio (U.B.) 24.04 so that I can do audio work. But it created problems with my video channel when teaching with Google Meet. My students heard very loud noise interference. I'm guessing because of U.S. being set for audio performance (nice touch).
Anyway, can't figure out how to fix that, so I'm thinking that maybe having a dual boot system with the standard Ubuntu 24.04, which worked fine previously, and U.S. 24.04 version is good way to go in order to avoid continually changing audio settings for different purposes.
Thing is, I'm not good with Linux. When I have some time I may do some study on it, as I love it. But for now, I require some assistance.
If anyone could walk me through the process, preferable with images, I would be highly thankful.
I guess I need to partition my hard drive and install Ubuntu on that at root level. Not sure what it the best way. I have only just done a clean install of U.S., so if it's easier to have two .iso files on memory sticks and start from fresh, that's not an issue.
Thank you all.
Regards,
